# Conflict between aspectj-autoproxy and spring security after configuring oauth2

Tags: spring, spring-security, aop, aspectj, spring-security-oauth2

whenever I add `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>` to my applicationContext.xml
with spring security beans configured I get the following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3a136b71' of type [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter] while setting constructor argument with key [4]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3a136b71': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy245 implementing java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Comparable,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' to required type 'boolean' for property 'eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy245 implementing java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Comparable,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [boolean] for property 'eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomBooleanEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy245 implementing java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Comparable,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4793)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5236)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:586)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:460)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1583)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1460)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:906)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:344)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2489)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3a136b71' of type [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter] while setting constructor argument with key [4]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3a136b71': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy245 implementing java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Comparable,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' to required type 'boolean' for property 'eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy245 implementing java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Comparable,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [boolean] for property 'eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomBooleanEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy245 implementing java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Comparable,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3a136b71': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy245 implementing java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Comparable,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' to required type 'boolean' for property 'eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy245 implementing java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Comparable,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [boolean] for property 'eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomBooleanEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy245 implementing java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Comparable,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy245 implementing java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Comparable,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' to required type 'boolean' for property 'eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy245 implementing java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Comparable,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [boolean] for property 'eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomBooleanEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy245 implementing java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Comparable,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy245 implementing java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Comparable,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' to required type 'boolean' for property 'eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy245 implementing java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Comparable,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [boolean] for property 'eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomBooleanEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy245 implementing java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Comparable,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:596)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertForProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:603)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    ... 88 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy245 implementing java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Comparable,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [boolean] for property 'eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomBooleanEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy245 implementing java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Comparable,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:576)
    ... 94 more
```

with the following spring security beans configuration

```
<bean id="passwordEncoder"
      class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <constructor-arg name="strength" value="11" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService">
        <sec:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"></sec:password-encoder>
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>


<bean id="tokenStore"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="tokenServices"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
    <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="4500" />
</bean>

<bean id="oAuth2RequestFactory"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>
<bean id="userApprovalHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler">
    <property name="requestFactory" ref="oAuth2RequestFactory" />
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
</bean>

<oauth:authorization-server
    client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
    user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
    <oauth:authorization-code />
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials />
    <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
                       token-services-ref="tokenServices" resource-id="rest_api" />

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Jsr250Voter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="Authorization/client" />
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</bean>


<bean id="caet"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="Authorization/client" />
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="Authorization" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="oAuth2ClientContextFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter">
</bean>



<sec:http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
          authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
          entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint">

    <sec:csrf  disabled="true"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="permitAll()"/>
    <sec:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
                       before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="oAuth2ClientContextFilter"
                       after="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER  " />
    <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />

</sec:http>

<sec:http pattern="/register" security="none"/>

<sec:http pattern="/**" create-session="never"
          authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
    <sec:csrf  disabled="true"/>
    <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />

    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" method="POST" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

    <sec:custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <sec:http-basic entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</sec:http>
```

What should I do to keep both aspectj and spring-security working together?